# Java determining if each character in a string is a letter

Tags: java

I'm using isLetter() and charAt() to see if a character in str is a letter or not.
The use of this method is to find the number of words in a string that are at least the minimum word length. I don't want it to count anything other than letters. (im a java noob)

```
public static int wordCount(String str, int minLength) {     
//Method that counts words.

    int count = 0;
    boolean isLetter = false;
    for (int i = 0, wordLength = 0; i < str.length() + 1; i++) {
        isLetter = Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)); //Why doesn't this line work?
        if (i == str.length() || str.charAt(i) == ' ' || isLetter==false) { 
            if (wordLength >= minLength) {              
                count++;                                                
            }
            wordLength = 0;                                 
        } else {                                                            
            wordLength++;                                       
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What about the isLetter check doesn't work for you?  It's used in a compound predicate that is OR'ed with a bunch of other conditions....

Comment: it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `for` loop. You have it iterate until `i < str.length() + 1`. That means at some point, you will be asking for `str.charAct(str.length())`. Because Java arrays (and Strings) index from 0, the index is too high and will break.

Instead, just have your `for` loop iterate until `i < str.length()`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `Character.isLetter` not working, it's the `str.charAt(i)` that throws an exception when `i` reaches `str.length()`.

Your loop iterates `i` from `0` to `str.length()`, inclusive - a total of `str.length()+1` characters. The call of `charAt(i)` when `i` is `str.length()` would be illegal.

To fix this problem, remove `+ 1` from the expression in the `for` loop, or make sure that `str.charAt(i)` is not called when `i` is equal to `str.length()`. For example, you could use the short-circuiting feature like this:

```
for (int i = 0, wordLength = 0; i < str.length() + 1; i++) {
    if (i == str.length() || !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Above, `str.charAt(i)` is not called when `i == str.length()`, preventing the crash ([demo](http://ideone.com/rFOrN1)).

You may want to change a few more things:

- `str.charAt(i) == ' ' || isLetter==false` can be reduced to `isLetter==false` or even to `!isLetter`, because space character is *not* a letter
- The declaration of `isLetter` can be moved inside the loop, and combined with initialization (unless you decide to get rid of the variable altogether using the code snipped shown above).

Comment: the code now runs after removing + 1 it still counts punctuations as a word, what can I do?

Comment: @javajavahut It does not count punctuation for me (you can see my modifications [here](http://ideone.com/rFOrN1)).

Comment: @javajavahut You are welcome! If the solution forks for you, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that your problem has been solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.